# Using pygame.time.get_ticks() to display remaining time

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame

I'm currently looking to display the time remaining for power ups on my scoreboard. I'm using pygame.time.get_ticks() to determine the remaining time left for a power up and it seems to be functioning as expected. When a power up is received it lasts for 5 seconds (5000 ticks), unless the same power up is picked up again, then the time is extended by another 5 seconds. This is determined by my power level; picking up a power up increases power up level by 1, once 5 seconds pass, decrease power level by 1.

I'm having trouble working out how to get this to properly display on my scoreboard, as currently it just displays -5000, which would be my starting power up time (0) minus my power up time allowed per level (5000). When a power up is picked up the time does not change at all and just stays at -5000.

[image: Example Image]

main.py

```
class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initlize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height

        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.stats = GameStats(self)
        self.sb = Scoreboard(self)

        self.ship = Ship(self)

        self._wall_setup()
        self._create_multiple_walls(*self.wall_x_positions,
                                    x_start=self.settings.screen_width / 8, y_start=850)

        self._create_groups()
        self._create_fleet()
        self._create_buttons()

    def run_game(self):
        """Start main loop for our game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()

            if self.stats.game_active:
                self.ship.update()
                self._update_bullets()
                self._check_bomb_ship_collisions()
                self._update_aliens()
                self._check_power_time()

            self._update_screen()

   def _check_pow_collisions(self):
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(
            self.ship, self.powerups, True
        )

        for collosion in collisions:
            if collosion.type == 'gun':
                self.settings.ship_power += 1
                self.settings.powerup_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                self._check_power_time()

            if collosion.type == 'shield' and self.stats.ships_left < 3:
                self.stats.ships_left += 1
                self.sb.prep_ships()

    def _check_power_time(self):
        if (self.settings.ship_power >= 2 and pygame.time.get_ticks() -
                self.settings.powerup_time > self.settings.POWERUP_TIME_ALLOWED):
            self.settings.ship_power -= 1
            self.settings.powerup_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on screen and flip to the new screen."""
        # fill our background with our bg_color
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)

        # draw scoreboard to screen
        self.sb.show_score()

        # draw ship to screen
        self.ship.blitme()

        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()

        self.alien_bombs.update()
        self.alien_bombs.draw(self.screen)

        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)

        self.powerups.draw(self.screen)
        self.powerups.update()
        self._check_pow_collisions()

        self.blocks.draw(self.screen)
        self._check_wall_collisions()

        # draw play button if game is inactive
        if not self.stats.game_active:
            if self.stats.level == 1:
                self.play_button.draw_button()

            elif not self.stats.ships_left:
                self.game_over_button.draw_button()
                pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

            elif self.stats.ships_left != 0:
                self.continue_button.draw_button()

        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        # this clears our previous screen and updates it to a new one
        # this gives our programe smooth movemnt
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    settings = Settings()

    ALIENBOMB = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(ALIENBOMB, settings.alien_bomb_speed)

    ai.run_game()
```

scoreboard.py

```
class Scoreboard:
    """a class to report score information"""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.ai_game = ai_game
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.stats = ai_game.stats

        # font settings for scoreboard
        self.text_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.font = pygame.font.Font('fonts/font.ttf', 20)

        self.prep_score()
        self.prep_high_score()
        self.prep_level()
        self.prep_remaining_pow_time()
        self.prep_empty_hearts()
        self.prep_ships()

    def prep_remaining_pow_time(self):
        """turn remainging pow time into an image"""
        pow_time_left = self.settings.powerup_time - self.settings.POWERUP_TIME_ALLOWED
        pow_time_str = "{}".format(pow_time_left)
        self.powtime_image = self.font.render(pow_time_str, True, 
        self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)

        # place image below score and level
        self.powtime_rect = self.powtime_image.get_rect()
        self.powtime_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.powtime_rect.top = self.level_rect.bottom + 10

  def show_score(self):
        """draw score to screen"""
        self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.high_score_image, self.high_score_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.level_image, self.level_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.powtime_image, self.powtime_rect)
        self.empty_hearts.draw(self.screen)
        self.ships.draw(self.screen)
```

settings.py

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store our settings for Alien Invasion game."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initlize the games settings."""
        # screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1600
        self.screen_height = 900
        self.bg_color = (0, 0, 0)

        # ship settings
        self.ship_limit = 3
        self.ship_power = 1
        self.POWERUP_TIME_ALLOWED = 5000

        # bullet settings
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = (255, 51, 51)
        self.bullets_allowed = 3
        self.upgraded_bullets_allowed = 6


        # alien settings
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
        self.increse_bomb_rate = 75

        # how quickly the game speeds up
        self.speedup_scale = 1.1

        # how muct alien poits value increses
        self.score_scale = 1.5

        self.initialize_dynamic_settings()

    def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):
        """settings that change through the game"""
        self.ship_speed = 1.5
        self.bullet_speed = 1.5

        self.alien_speed = 0.5

        self.alien_bomb_speed = 999
        self.wall_speed = 0.5

        self.fleet_direction = 1

        # scoring
        self.alien_points = 50

        self.powerup_time = 0

    def increse_speed(self):
        """increse speed settings"""
        self.ship_speed *= self.speedup_scale
        self.bullet_speed *= self.speedup_scale
        self.alien_speed *= self.speedup_scale
        self.wall_speed *= self.speedup_scale
        self.alien_bomb_speed -= self.increse_bomb_rate

        self.alien_points = int(self.alien_points * self.score_scale)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only doing the following two things once since `prep_remaining_pow_time` is called in init.

```
pow_time_str = "{}".format(pow_time_left)
self.powtime_image = self.font.render(pow_time_str, True, 
        self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)
```

You need to do it every frame for the `self.powtime_image` to be updated with the latest `pow_time_left` value.